# Replacing the 2015 Fiesta S's ugly chrome grill with a Euro kit?

Tags: ford, body-work, fiesta

So I have a 2015 Fiesta S (the one with the chrome braces[image: This one])

I'm hoping that the kit that I found on fordpartsuk will work, as it seems like it's the same shape...

[image: This is the kit that I hope fits]
http://www.fordpartsuk.com/shop/ford_fiesta_sporty_grille_kit_from_2012_to_2014_f_KITFIETRIM18.htm

Anybody have any experience doing this kinda swap on a US Fiesta?

Comment: Do you have a link to the exact kit you're looking at? Maybe a part number and manufacturer?

Comment: Gaah, totally meant to include that: http://www.fordpartsuk.com/shop/ford_fiesta_sporty_grille_kit_from_2012_to_2014_f_KITFIETRIM18.htm